# SendGrid Templates with Web API vs. SMTP API

Tags: email, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I have gone through various documentation of SendGrid Implementation. Actually, I want to use Email Templates defined in the SendGrid.

I only found that we can use Email Templates and can use substitution tags in it **if we are implementing SendGrid SMTP API**.

I want to make it confirm that, can we use **Email Templates** with **substitution tags** in it, if we are using SendGrid via **Web API**?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh Yes!

After going through some SendGrid mail examples on GitHub. I got that **we can use Email Templates + Substitution tags** if we are using the **SendGrid Web APIs**.

Here is the link from where I got to know this -

[SendGrid Java examples for various scenarios on GitHub.](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/blob/master/examples/mail/mail.java)

Thanks if someone was looking into it!